blazor mudblazor extend component ? make label on top clickable? or add button after it?
I known hot to use mudblazor / but im not a UI developer so if someone can point me a direction i would be very happy ;)
Lets say that i have a simple mudtext component
<MudTextField @bind-Value="TextValue" Label="Standard" Variant="Variant.Text"></MudTextField>

and i would need to create some wrapper around it that will add some icon after it with hisotry of the field (not allow it to be upper / lower / just after the component always)
so at the end i would like it to be as
<HistoryWrapper @icon="someMudblazorIcon" @onclick="someMethodThatWillOpenPopupWindowWithHistry">
    <MudTextField @bind-Value="TextValue" Label="Standard" Variant="Variant.Text"></MudTextField>
</HistoryWrapper >

please point me god direction to do this? shoud i do this using renderfragment? ot some better way?
thanks and regards

There are several ways to do this.  My prefered option is to inherit from the base control and add the extra functionality.
Here's an example where I add an icon to MudTextField.  The trick is to capture the base BuildRenderTree content into a RenderFragment delegate and then add it at the appropriate position in the child component's markup.  They key benefit in doing it this way is you don't need to implement a lot of passthrough code.
@inherits MudTextField<T>
@typeparam T

<MudGrid>
    <MudItem>
        @_content
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem>
        <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Custom.Brands.Microsoft" Title="API" @onclick="this.OnClick"/>
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
<div >
</div>

@code {
    private RenderFragment? _content => (builder) => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);

    private Task OnClick()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

However, in your specific case, you can probably use the standard MudTextField control using the Adornment parameters and specifically OnAdornmentClick.

<MudTextField 
    @bind-Value="_string" 
    Label="Clearable Standard" 
    Variant="Variant.Text" 
    Clearable="true" 
    Adornment="Adornment.End" 
    AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Custom.Brands.MudBlazor" 
    AdornmentColor="Color.Primary"
    OnAdornmentClick="this.OnAdornmentClicked"
    Immediate="true" />

@code {
    private string? _string;

    private Task OnAdornmentClicked()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}


thanks for Your answer  / please leave it / i will check this extenssion option tommorow/ i did not thought that mudcomponent can be extended ;)  but still is there a wa to do this as i proposed <HistoryWrapper > ? this way i do not need to inherit multiple types of input components not only textfield as it is example only/ this way it would be more universal. also i known about AdornmentIcon/OnAdornmentClick but the same / it is for one specyfic / mudselect does not support this so it need to be external. thanks

Yes you can do it your way, but you need to pass through all the Parameters and wire up the binding on the internal control.

please show how if You can / i have something in my mind but i think it must be simpler way also is this 
 needed? also thanks i see now that it is T so no need to inherit multiple nice
i called it FieldHistoryExtMudTextField so when i use it as     <FieldHistoryExtMudTextField  @bind-Value="test2"> then i get :
Error (active) RZ9991 The attribute names could not be inferred from bind attribute 'bind-Value'. Bind attributes should be of the form 'bind' or 'bind-value' along with their corresponding optional parameters like 'bind-value:event', 'bind:format' etc.
